# How to validate array of date that have to be inside two other date relative to a model in Laravel 51

Tags: php, validation, request, laravel-5.1, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using boostrap-datepicker, with "multiple-date" option activated.
My `dates` looks like this: `[date1, date2, ...]`.

I'm also using an hidden input to retrieve an "id". This "id" help me to retrieve "startdate" and "enddate" inside my model.

So I'm looking for a validation rule who can tell me if my dates are valid and if they are inside two other dates that correspond to the "id" of my model.

For now my `id` and `dates` rules are like this:

```
$rules = [
    'id' => 'required|numeric|exists:event,id,isactive,1',
    'dates' => 'array'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in  very simple manner like this

Here is the documentation about writing rules for [before](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-before) and [after](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-after)

```
protected $rules = array(
    'afterdate' => 'after:'.$yourDateForm,
    'beforedate' => 'before:'.$yourDateTo 
);
```

**Note :**

You shall also extend your date validation like this

```
'start_date' => 'required|date|after:tomorrow'
'finish_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date'
```

**Update :**

As the OP wants to get the date from db,

You shall do like this

```
$yourStartDate = Call to get Start Date from Table;
$yourEndDate = Call to get End Date from Table;
```

and the rule shall be

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array('date' => $yourStartDate),
    array('date' => 'after:'.$yourEndDate)
);
```

Comment: My problem is a little more complex, I might have not be clear enough. I have to access start_date and end_date from a model, that I retrieve with an "id" also inside my request. Also, I have to validate every date inside my "dates" attribute.

Comment: Ok, why not you  pass get the value from db then pass the start and end date to the validation rule ?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do that, could you give me an hint ?

Comment: Sure, You want to retrieve the date of the matching column which you gets as input ?

Comment: Exactly, something like this : $event = Event::whereId(id), now I want $event->enddate and $event->begindate. But I don't know how to tell that to Laravel rules.

Comment: Cool, will update answer in few minutes , was in ride ;)

Comment: @Hayanno Updated the answer .. You shall declare the rule inside the controller ;)

Comment: My problem is that in $yourStartDate = Call to get Start Date from Table; I have to select the entry with "id" being the "id" I retrieve from my Form. And I don't know how to use this "id" because he is not currently validated, so it might cause security issue.

Comment: I solved my problem using double Validator, one for my "id" only, then every other attribute, I hope it's good security practice.